# Exception in Application constructor in JavaFX project

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I migrate my old JavaFX project to JavaFX-maven. I use openjdk-17 for this. When I starts this code, I catch exception in Application constructor. Maybe I uses incorrect libriries? But then why compiler says okay when build my project?

My stack trace

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class classes.Main
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:891)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class classes.Main (in module com.example.javacoursework) because module com.example.javacoursework does not export classes to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
```

My code

```
package classes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main extends Application //Error occured in constructor!?
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException
    {
        Button button = new Button("Hello");
        Scene scene = new Scene(button);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
//        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("../../resources/123.fxml")));
//        primaryStage.setTitle("Vote app");
//        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
//        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
//        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //launch(args);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

If need more info, I will add to this post.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaFX framework instantiates your `Application` implementation class using reflection. Code can only reflectively access code in a separate module if the necessary "permissions" are given by said module. An `IllegalAccessException` will be thrown if those "permissions" are not given.

Here is your root exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class classes.Main (in module com.example.javacoursework) because module com.example.javacoursework does not export classes to module javafx.graphics
```

The fix is simple. Just add the following directive to your module-info descriptor (`module-info.java`):

```java
exports classes to javafx.graphics;
```

Which package needs to be exported, and to which module it needs to be exported, can be determined by reading the exception message. Note you only need to use `exports`, instead of `opens`, because the JavaFX application class and its constructor are required to be `public`.

---

It may help to read: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code. It's your project/launch setup. Go here and have a look at how to configure Maven correctly. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/